# MVC6 input asp-for not change model property value

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying update a model property value, but in the httpost doesn't reflect the new value entered, shows the original value.
Thanks for your help.

```
<div class="row row-padding">
<section class="form-field">
    <input asp-for="bidDataProcess.MaxBidPosted" type="number" class="form-control" />
    <form asp-controller="Item" asp-action="PlaceBid" asp-route-ItemId="@Model.itemDescription.ItemId"  asp-route-MaxBid="@Model.bidDataProcess.MaxBidPosted" method="post" class="clearfix">
        <input id="PlaceBid" type="submit" style="background-color:blue;color:white; font-weight:bold;width:50%" class="form-control text-center" value="Place Bid" />
   </form>
</section>
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlaceBid(int ItemId, decimal MaxBid)
{
// Maxbid resturns the original value  not the new value entered.
decimal maxBid = MaxBid;
return View();
}
```

Comment: Is it not because the input tag is outside your form opening and closing tag?

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to duplicate the textbox form elements as both inputs and routevalues.
- Your MaxBidPosted input needs to be inside your form tags otherwise MaxBid in the controller  will be zero
- Your input name (MaxBidPosted) needs to match your controller parameter (MaxBid) otherwise MaxBid in the controller will be zero

cshtml:

```
    <div class="row row-padding">
        <section class="form-field">
            <form asp-controller="Item" asp-action="PlaceBid" asp-route-ItemId="@Model.ItemId" method="post" class="clearfix">
                <input asp-for="MaxBidPosted" type="number" class="form-control" />
                <input id="PlaceBid" type="submit" style="background-color:blue;color:white; font-weight:bold;width:50%" class="form-control text-center" value="Place Bid" />
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int ItemId, decimal MaxBidPosted)
    {
        decimal maxBid = MaxBidPosted;
        return View();
    }
```